# Recharts CustomTooltip loses background opacity

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I first came across this when implementing my own CustomTooltip, but I think this might actually be a recharts bug, as even the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-with-customized-content-lyxvs) from the documentation site has the same issue. If you remove 'content={< CustomTooltip />}' from line 110 on that codesandbox, you'll turn the tooltip into a basic one, which will look like this:

[image]

But when you put that piece back in so that it's what the documentation has as an example for a CustomTooltip, the background (for lack of a better term) of the tooltip disappears.

[image]

Does anyone know if this is a recharts bug, or maybe I'm just doing something wrong? I just want to get my Custom Tooltip to have the same visual look as the basic one

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. As rahuuzz said, providing custom content for the tooltip also overrides the base styling, so that has to be provided. My tooltip in my chart now looks like this:

```
<Tooltip 
    content={<CustomTooltip />}
    wrapperStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white", borderStyle: "ridge", paddingLeft: "10px", paddingRight: "10px" }}
/>
```

Basically just had to add the wrappedStyle prop with some basic styling. Hopefully this helps someone else googling in the future

Answer (score 0):

In your codesandbox you are importing `styles.css` but It doesnt contain any styles for **custom-tooltip** class.

When you provide custom content for the tooltip you have to define the styles yourself. When `content` prop is omitted, the package sets the style internally to the tooltip.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize providing custom content overrid the style. I came across this issue in my own code but that codesandbox is actually from recharts own documentation https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomContentOfTooltip

Do you know how I find out what the default styles are so I can set them myself?

Comment: right click, then inspect ;) Oh and you might have to hit pause script execution after hovering on the tooltip otherwise you cant get to view tooltip element